# Teller Scan 230 check scanner device - API documentation or sample needed for Delphi

Tags: delphi, usb

I recently bought a second hand TellerScan 230 which is a check scanning device made by www.digitalcheck.com that interfaces via a USB connection.

I downloaded the drivers and a demo program, however i can't find any api toolkit.

Can anyone help me to communicate with thist device. I work with Delphi XE2, however any other demo than includes the sources will be fine.

Comment: You can request the api toolkit from [here](http://www.e-maillogic.com/digitalcheck/digitalcom/tsenhacements.htm).

Comment: Any option for a demo in any language with sources? Thanks in advance

Comment: I improved your question by adding what the thing is.  (Expecting everyone or anyone on stackoverflow to know what BrandName is without Manufacturer, is kind of weak)

Answer (score 2):

You have to request the api toolkit from the vendor, from [here](http://www.e-maillogic.com/digitalcheck/digitalcom/tsenhacements.htm).

The api is featured in [`this`](http://www.digitalcheck.com/drivers_demo/api_webdoc.pdf) document, an `ActiveX` control with samples in VB,.net,C,C++.

Comment: Any other Free solution?  For me its very expensive buy the API ToolKit I only need a demo with source code in any language and I can develop one in Delphi and share it too.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the API toolkit is not free upon request? It's quite common for vendors to let customers/users have tools for free once registered. And no, I haven't searched for demo code. But you can try with various search patterns with VB,C++ etc.